# Rigidbody being accessed from different scripts at the same time

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-mixed-reality

I have am using two mixed reality controllers at the same time.  The right and left trigger both do different things in my game.  The problem is that I can only have one of them access the rigidbody at a time.  If the left controller has the script attached it will work correctly.  If the right controller has the script attached it will work correctly.  But I cannot get both of them to work at the same time.  I attached the code below.  This script is on both controllers.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Valve.VR;

public class ControllerRight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ballObj;
    Rigidbody rb;

    public SteamVR_Behaviour_Pose pose;
    public SteamVR_Input_Sources handType;
    public SteamVR_Action_Single clickTrigger;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        rb = ballObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger Status: " + clickTrigger.GetAxis(handType));
        if (clickTrigger.GetAxis(handType) > 0.5)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.forward * clickTrigger.GetAxis(handType) * 10;
        }
        else if (clickTrigger.GetAxis(handType) == 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour if both controllers were to work at the same time? You're directly overwriting to velocity, so the behaviours won't blend.

Comment: Find a solution for this? I have a similar issue where several MonoBehaviors, `Move`, `Jump` and `Dash`, modify velocity of the same RigidBody2D. However, I'd like to implement a gravity-free air dash, and so need some means by which to block other MonoBehaviors from modifying the RigidBody2D when Dash op occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting rigidbody's velocity, try to apply a force in the direction of input. That way, two controllers will not override each other, but result in some combined movement.